# Firebase and AngularJS - get data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The data is to update in the UI in the model. But I keep getting empty in the database. I have set

```
$scope.user = userData;
```

Please help.
Here's my controller

```
var contactModule = angular.module('test.contact', ['ngRoute','firebase','angularModalService'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
        templateUrl: 'contact/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('ContactCtrl', ["$scope","$firebase","$firebaseArray", "$firebaseObject","ModalService", "fireBaseService",function($scope, $firebase, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, ModalService, fireBaseService ) {

    $scope.contacts = fireBaseService.getContacts();
    $scope.showAddForm = function () {            
        $scope.addFormShow = true;
    };
    $scope.user = fireBaseService.getUser(null);
    $scope.showView = function(contact) {
        var userData = fireBaseService.getUser(contact.$id);
        userData.$loaded().then(function () {
        });
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: 'Modals/modal.html',
            controller: "ModalController"
        })
            .then(function(modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                //Modal is closed now.
            });
        });
    };

}])

.controller('ModalController', function($scope, close) {
$scope.close = function(result) {
    close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
};
});


testContactsApplication.factory('fireBaseService',["$q","$firebase","$firebaseArray", "$firebaseObject",function($q, $firebase, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
    var list = [];
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var dataObjectArray = $firebaseObject(rootRef);
    var contactRef = firebase.database().ref().child("contacts");


    return {
        getContacts: getContacts,
        getUser: getUser
    };
    function getUser(userID) {
        if(userID===null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else {

            var user = contactRef.child(userID);
            var userData = $firebaseObject(user);
            return userData;


        }
    }

    function getContacts() {
        list = $firebaseArray(rootRef.child('contacts'));
        return list;
    }

}])
;
```

My view:

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close(false)" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{user.name}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid span6">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-4" >
                        <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/de9b11d0f9c0569ba917393ed5e5b3ab?s=140&r=g&d=mm" class="img-circle">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h3>{{user.name}}</h3>
                        <h6>Email: {{user.email}}</h6>
                        <h6>Status: {{user.status | capitalize}}</h6>
                        <h6>Type: {{user.type}}</h6>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" ng-click="close(false)" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```